# How can I include a conversion from one database type to another entity type with EF5?

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server, entity-framework, sqlite

The use case is the following: I have a SQLite database and a SQL Server database that are identical. Some users of the product will use the SQLite version, some the SQL Server version. However, by default, the primary key of SQLite, regardless of your `CREATE TABLE` statement, will internally be stored as a 64 bit integer and the default for our SQL Server is a 32 bit and sometimes a 16 bit integer.

Because we are talking about large amounts of records, the space needed to store the tables and indexes changes dramatically if we match the datatypes to be 64 bit in both types of databases.

I would like to use a single mapping with Entity Framework, if at all possible, for the entity types. This works for most fields, but not for the primary key fields. Even if the mapping maps to `int`, and the field in SQLite is an `INT`, as soon as I try to load the data, I will receive:

> InvalidOperationException: The type of the key field 'CustomerId' is expected to be System.Int32 but the value provided is actually of type 'System.Int64'

I understand the reason of the exception: the SQLite driver returns an `Int64`. I do not get this error with other fields in the tables (i.e., other DDL declarations of `INT` map to `Int32` and do not throw this error).

I was wondering if there is an extension point in the Entity Framework, or another solution, some place where I can simply say: "just cast it to an `Int32`, it is safe to do so".

Current ideas involve creating different libraries and dynamic mapping, or some creative generics, but none of the ideas we've had seem satisfiable. Any thoughts?

Answering Matthew's question, table are defined with the following pattern:

```sql
-- works
CREATE TABLE [Customer] (
  [CustomerId] INTEGER NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY ON CONFLICT FAIL, 
  [Name] CHAR NOT NULL ON CONFLICT FAIL);

-- works not (throws above error, unless I manually change 
-- type in EDMX to from int to integer and Int32 to Int64)
CREATE TABLE [Customer] (
  [CustomerId] INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY ON CONFLICT FAIL, 
  [Name] CHAR NOT NULL ON CONFLICT FAIL);
```

Comment: How is the SQLite table defined?

Comment: @Matthew: I updated the question to include an example. Oddly enough, I have just found out that the error is not thrown always. I am now going one by one through the DDL, from `INTEGER` to `INT`, trying to find whether one particular situation causes this behavior.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is an old question, but I had a similar problem and here's what I did.

I am working with the same entities in both sql server and sqlite using EF6. I was getting the mentioned error when querying using sqlite

`cntx.Set<T>().FirstOrDefault(a => a.ActivityDescription == activityDescription);`.

My key was created like `[VSDebugBreakModeEnterEventArgsId] INTEGER NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT` in my sqlite db.

I was able to change the key on the model to `Int64` instead of `int` and that fixed the problem. I didnt have to change anything in my sql server db schema to accommodate this. The entity can be inserted, updated, deleted, and queried using an ef context backed by either sqlite or sql server databases.

Also, this behavior only occurred after I upgraded my ef nugets to EF 6.1.1 from ???. At one point there were 3 different projects using 3 different versions of ef and I decided to upgrade them all to the same version. Thats when the above exception started happening.

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to answer this old question. I recently happened to run into the same issue with a different project but we resolved it by simply disallowing sqlite for the time being. So I'm very happy to know there's a workaround available now!